# no Objective-C description available - Why?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

I really have no idea why on this particular project my debugger is extremely 'disabled'.

For example I'll want to get info on an object:

`(lldb) po [_model dictionaryValue]

[no Objective-C description available]`

I'm wondering why this is.  It's making debugging extremely difficult and it's only on this current project.  I'm guessing I've done something to the settings at some point.  It's on almost any `po someObject` I try to inspect.  The variables in scope can be seen in the pane to the left of the debug console however.

I'm on Xcode 5, I have Cocoapods in my project, and it's a Unit Testing Target.

Any insights or any way to fix this?

Update:

For clarity, part of how the test case is implemented:

```
@interface WWCGateModelTests : XCTestCase  
{  
    WWCGate *_model;  
}  
@end  

@implementation WWCGateModelTests  
- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here; it will be run once, before each test case.

    _model = [WWCGate loadGateModelWithIdentifier: kGateName];  // defined, not nil
}

- (void)tearDown  
{  
    [super tearDown];  

    NSError *error = nil;
    [_model saveModelOrError:&error];

    // Breakpoint here.  po _model does not print the model.    
    // This has been possible with other projects...  po error will print  
    // nil to the console.  How is an ivar not in scope?
}
```

Comment: What do you get for `po _model`?

Comment: erm... did you read the question?  :-)  [no Objective-C description available]

Comment: Nice way to answer someone who's trying to help you. I was going to carry on and ask where you are making your call, is it in scope, what is the return value of the `dictionaryValue` method. But I seem to be too thick to understand your question.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to be rude.  But it was pretty clearly written what happens.  I'll say it another way:  what normally works in other projects isn't working in this one.  I'm in scope because my breakpoint stops inside the method with that variable in it.  po someObject is returning the same thing

Comment: Question:  Where do you set a value into _model?

Comment: (I have had this symptom from time to time when the debugger was stopped at an "odd" place, but it's always cleared up.)

Comment: (And note that you get this symptom sometimes when you attempt to po a non-object address.  Try `p` and see what it says.)

Comment: @HotLicks setUp method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tracked down the issue (but haven't fixed it fully yet).  It has to do with the Mantle Framework.  In its description method it wants to spit out the contents of an NSDictionary that it generates at that point.  There's something wrong with the way I set up my model I believe so creating this dictionary (based probably on how I configured some property) is basically failing.

I overrode the description method to return a standard description:

```
- (NSString*)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@: %p>", self.class, self];
}
```

and everything is fine and good again on planet Earth.  ;-)

Thanks to those who were particularly patient.  A more detailed discussion about this issue can be found at UPDATE 3 of the following post: http://horseshoe7.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/hands-on-with-the-mantle-model-framework/

Answer (score 3):

This is likely happening because Unit Testing Targets typically are set up to run with "Release" configurations.  "Release" configurations are ones where the debugging symbols have been stripped or optimized away.

I suspect you won't have this problem if you make certain you're running with a non-optimized, symbols-in-place Debug version of your app.  You can change that in Xcode's scheme editor (e.g. when doing "Test" or "Profile", use the "Debug" configuration).

Comment: Yes, it's already set to that in the scheme.  Even so, if my Test target is set to debug configuration does that mean the Pods are also built with debug config?  (My Data models that I'm testing are based on the Mantle Framework, which is a Pod in my project)

Comment: `po someObject` prints the return value of `[someObject description]`, and that should be available even in Release builds (it is part of the NSObject protocol and all NSObjects conform to).

Comment: [We're having a debate on NSChat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15942/nschat) about what the O.P.'s problem is.  Maybe he's calling "`po`" on a variable that's out of scope?  Either way, we probably need more info to go with.

Comment: Probably he is trying to `po` an object that is out of scope !?

Comment: breakpoint in method.  In left pane (i.e. beside console output) the variable can be inspected.  just po not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't using it on primitive types? Use `p intVariable` on those.

Every object will respond to `description` by at least printing class and memory address.

Comment: very sure. :-) po anInteger will also yield a different response from the debugger

Comment: Hmm... what happens for `po [object description]?`

Comment: if po _model doesn't work, I can't imagine how any method on it would.  But anyway, same thing.

Comment: And what about `p object`?

Comment: gives me a pointer address:  
(lldb) p _model
(WWCGate *) $0 = 0x09963c50

Comment: if you can, please upvote the question.  I'm told it increases visibility.  This is a pretty annoying problem to have one arm tied behind your back when trying to debug...

Comment: I'm quite amazed... perhaps the class `WWCGate` has by mistake overridden `-description`? What if you do `p` and `po` for `[_model class]`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42140/discussion-between-ilya-n-and-horseshoe7)

Comment: that's not it.  and overriding description is a common practice.  and hasn't yielded this behaviour before.